# Is this storing correctly using local storage?

Tags: javascript, foreach, local-storage

I used a `for each loop` to store each task created and pushed to the `tasklist` array.

So the task that are being created are storing in the local storage, but I am not sure if it is stored correctly?

[image: Stored date]

JS code

```
//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
function display(task) {
  
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };
  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
       <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button onclick="editItem()" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
        <button onclick="deleteItem()" class="delete" data- 
        id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="completeItem()" class="complete" data 
        id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(data);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
}

taskList.forEach(display)

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stored correctly"? Does your app work?

Comment: What makes you unsure?

Comment: What makes me unsure is that, if local storage is used, aren't the tasks meant to stay on the list even when the browser refreshes? That is why I am asking the question.

Because currently the tasks disappear from the list when the browser is refreshed

Comment: If that's the issue, we need the code that _reads_ from localStorage. Because the screenshot seems to confirm that correct-looking data has been stored (no obvious errors there, theres an array and it contains data).

Comment: hey @somethinghere, I added the code below of the screenshot or unless that is the step I am missing because I have the local storage that sets and gets in on function under ```function storeList()````

Comment: But you don't do anything with your `getItem`, you need to get the item, parse it and then recreate your content on dom load. You also can't do this in the same method - because first you will store something empty, then you will read back something empty. Just `JSON.parse` ing you data doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes on how to read it back from localStorage below. I restructured it a bit and added comments that hopefully makes clear what flow you should follow:

- read
- render
- (optionally add and render the new additions)
- save

```js
// You need to start your initial array by reading the old value you stored from localStorage, like the below. I added `?? '[]'` to ensure the result _will always be an array_ even before you added anything to localStorage.
let taskList = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( STORAGE_KEY ) ?? '[]' );

// I split this off, since you want to separate the rendering of your content from the generating of your content. Otherwise, when you read it back in it will just be some new random gibberish.
function makeNewTask() {
  
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };
  
  return data;
  
}
function display( data ){
  
  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
       <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button onclick="editItem()" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
        <button onclick="deleteItem()" class="delete" data- 
        id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="completeItem()" class="complete" data 
        id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(data);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  
}

// Because our taskList has been populated by localStorage (or not and is still empty), this will just render your initial content
taskList.forEach( display );

// Only store it here, no need to read it back out.
function storeList() {

    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));

}
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that snippets are sandboxed, which prevents demonstrating storage and other concepts.  +1

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks to be a better way of doing what I did, thank you. I ran into an error though.

1. It seems that the following are causing issues ```${data.id}```, ```${data.taskNew}```,```${data.taskDate}```,```${data.taskTime}```. I think it has to do with the data object that is not passing through to the ```function display( data )```

Comment: I can't really help with that, try to log the incoming `data` argument in the `display` function and see what comes out and whether its an object containing all that or not, you might be storing incorrect data or some other small oversight. Logs everything until you can see whats going on!